# How to use get_close_matches to modify values of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, dataset

I have two datasets i want to merge them by "university_name" to put the 'country' column of the second dataset into the first, but many university names are different, so i would something that see if a name is similar and then modify it. I tried this but it takes a lot of time (shanghai is almost 5000 rows), I tried with a smaller dataframe but it modify the rows with only one letter i don't know why.

```
import difflib
shanghai['university_name'] = shanghai['university_name'].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, sact['university_name']))
```

These are the two datasets(a part):

Shanghai

```
world_rank  university_name national_rank   total_score alumni  award   hici    ns  pub pcp year
0   1   Harvard University  1   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0   72.4    2005
1   2   University of Cambridge 1   73.6    99.8    93.4    53.3    56.6    70.9    66.9    2005
2   3   Stanford University 2   73.4    41.1    72.2    88.5    70.9    72.3    65.0    2005
3   4   University of California, Berkeley  3   72.8    71.8    76.0    69.4    73.9    72.2    52.7    2005
4   5   Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT) 4   70.1    74.0    80.6    66.7    65.8    64.3    53.0    2005
5   6   California Institute of Technology  5   67.1    59.2    68.6    59.8    65.8    52.5    100.0   2005
6   7   Columbia University 6   62.3    79.4    60.6    56.1    54.2    69.5    45.4    2005
7   8   Princeton University    7   60.9    63.4    76.8    60.9    48.7    48.5    59.1    2005
8   9   University of Chicago   8   60.1    75.6    81.9    50.3    44.7    56.4    42.2    2005
9   10  University of Oxford    2   59.7    64.3    59.1    48.4    55.6    68.4    53.2    2005
10  11  Yale University 9   56.9    52.1    44.5    60.3    57.2    63.9    49.3    2005
```

sact

```
university_name country
0   Harvard University  United States of America
1   California Institute of Technology  United States of America
2   Massachusetts Institute of Technology   United States of America
3   Stanford University United States of America
4   Princeton University    United States of America
5   University of Cambridge United Kingdom
6   University of Oxford    United Kingdom
7   University of California, Berkeley  United States of America
8   Imperial College London United Kingdom
9   Yale University United States of America
10  University of California, Los Angeles   United States of America
```

Sorry if the dataframes are not aligned but i'm a beginner with both python and stackoverflow, i hope you understand.
Obviously it's not important for me to use get_close_matches, if there is a better way it's best for everyone.

Comment: how many rows does `sact` have? and how long does it currently take?

Comment: sact has 818 rows, shanghai 4897. Anyway i was wrong, it takes about 5 minutes but it gives me the error 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable'.

Answer (score 0):

To get results faster you can break your approach in 2 steps:

1. Merge the data for the universities with the same name in both dataframes.
2. Filter the rows with the missing values and apply the similarity mapping.

This method applyed to your test data was around 6 times faster (it depends on how many different values do you have in your complete data)

If `difflib.get_close_matches` doesn't find any match for a single university_name and you get an error:

```py
import difflib

def fn(x): 
    try:
        l = difflib.get_close_matches(x, sact['university_name'])[0]
        return l
    except Exception:
        return None

df = Shanghai.merge(sact, on='university_name', how='left')

df.loc[df.country.isna(), 'country'] = \
    sact.loc[sact.university_name.isin(
        df.loc[df.country.isna(), 'university_name']
        .apply(fn)
    ), 'country'].values
```

Output für `df[['university_name', 'country']]`:

```py
                                university_name                   country
0                            Harvard University  United States of America
1                       University of Cambridge            United Kingdom
2                           Stanford University  United States of America
3            University of California, Berkeley  United States of America
4   Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)  United States of America
5            California Institute of Technology  United States of America
6                           Columbia University            United Kingdom
7                          Princeton University  United States of America
8                         University of Chicago  United States of America
9                          University of Oxford            United Kingdom
10                              Yale University  United States of America
```

Note that `difflib.get_close_matches` is not 100% accurate like you may see in row index `6`.

Here I paste the comparison between the universities and the output of `difflib.get_close_matches`:

```py
    uni_Shanghai_df                                 similar_uni_with_get_close_matches
--  --------------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
0   Harvard University                              Harvard University
1   University of Cambridge                         University of Cambridge
2   Stanford University                             Stanford University
3   University of California, Berkeley              University of California, Berkeley
4   Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)     Massachusetts Institute of Technology
5   California Institute of Technology              California Institute of Technology
6   Columbia University                             Yale University
7   Princeton University                            Princeton University
8   University of Chicago                           University of Cambridge
9   University of Oxford                            University of Oxford
10  Yale University                                 Yale University
```

You could also create your own similarity matcher that fits better your need than `difflib.get_close_matches`.

Comment: First of all thank you, but it gives me this error:
 ----> 8         .apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, sact['university_name'])[0])), 'country'].values

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I edited the answer to handle the error. Let me know if it works

Comment: df2 is not defined. If i edit with "df" it gives me referring to the same row: typeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: sorry, `df2` is actually `sact`

Comment: Unfortunately i have the same error in the same row :/... TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
Thank you for the patience

Comment: @SimoneA I've changed the code with the last thing I can think of. It is really hard to debug because I don't have the piece of data that generates the error